# How to add a string to cursor point of gvim through a shell script

Tags: cursor-movement, terminal, invocation, gvim, persistent-state

When gvim is opened it saves the cursor position whether it is minimized or not. So I'm curious whether it is possible to add a string starting from the cursor blinking position by running a shell script or through a terminal.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question a bit, giving some example? As I'm not clear what's asked exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take note of the server name of your GVim window by looking at its title, it should have something like `VIM` or `VIM1`.

You can then use this command to insert `foo` at the current cursor position:

```
$ vim --servername VIM --remote-send "ifoo<Esc>"
```

For more information, see `:help clientserver`.

Answer (score 0):

`vim -c command` lets you specify a command to be executed on the first loaded file.

When last exiting, Vim saved the location of the cursor as the mark named `"`.  The normal-mode command to go to that mark would be <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>.  The ex-command version of that would be `:norm '"`.  Once at that location, to insert the string `hello`, you would use `ihello`.

```
$ vim -c "norm '\"ihello" file.txt
```